# Why dataframe exports only last value of iteration to csv? (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I am exporting results from dataframe to CSV, but it only exports the last value of the iteration. Please check my code and let me know, where I am doing wrong. Thank you for your support.

```
from pyswmm import Simulation, LidGroups, Nodes
from pyswmm.swmm5 import SWMMException
import os
import pandas as pd



output_path = "E:\VARS_Research\pyswmm_master\Test_Model\Test_Model_Manual"
output_csv_file = "node_flow.csv"

with Simulation('Test_model_LID.inp') as sim:
    nodes = Nodes(sim)
    
    for step in sim:
        j1 = Nodes(sim)["J1"]
        j2 = Nodes(sim)["J2"]
        j3 = Nodes(sim)["J3"]
        j4 = Nodes(sim)["J4"]
        results = {j1.total_inflow, j2.total_inflow, j3.total_inflow, j4.total_inflow} 
        sim.step_advance(300)
        
        for i in results:
            current_time = sim.current_time
            my_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'j1': [j1.total_inflow], 'j2': [j2.total_inflow], 'j3': [j3.total_inflow], 'j4': [j4.total_inflow]})
            my_df.to_csv(os.path.join(output_path, "node_flow.csv"))
```

Answer (score 0):

In each iteration over `results` you write to csv file overwriting the previous file. Not sure if that's what you want, but specify `mode='a'` in `to_csv()`. The default mode is `w`

[Link to docs for `to_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)